# performance issues applying double lambda functions

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, lambda

I have two dataframes: df1, df2 which contain each a column with names. I compare every name in df1 with every name in df2. 
This has to be an approximate match. Iam using fuzzywuzzy token_sort_ratio to get a comparison score.

However this method is very slow and df2 keeps growing, it already takes more then half an hour (4k x 2k rows).
Is there a way to speed up the process?

My current implementation:

```
def match(df2,name):
    df2['score'] = df2['name'].map(lambda x: fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, name))
        return df2.loc[(df2['score'].idxmax())

df1['result']=df1['name'].map(lambda x: match(df2,x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def similarity(name1, name2):
    return fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name1, name2)

df1['key'] = 1
df2['key'] = 1
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='key')

merged['name_score'] = merged[['name_x', 'name_y']] \
    .apply(lambda row: similarity(row['name_x'], row['name_y']), axis=1)
```

or,

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def similarity(name1, name2):
    return fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name1, name2)

df1['key'] = 1
df2['key'] = 1
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='key')

scores = list(map(similarity, merged['name_x'], merged['name_y']))
merged['name_score'] = scores
```